# ggplot does not find the value that is present in the dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)

graph <- structure(list(Constraint = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("Major Constraint", "Minor Constraint", 
"Moderate Constraint", "No Constraint", "Total"), class = "factor"), 
    `Observation for Crime = 0` = c(3124, 2484, 3511, 4646, 13765, 
    3124, 2484, 3511, 4646, 13765), `Observation for Crime = 1` = c(762, 
    629, 1118, 1677, 4186, 762, 629, 1118, 1677, 4186), `Total Observations` = c(3886, 
    3113, 4629, 6323, 17951, 3886, 3113, 4629, 6323, 17951), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Crime = 0", "Crime = 1"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(80.3911477097272, 79.79441053646, 75.847915316483, 
    73.4777795350308, 76.6809648487549, 19.6088522902728, 20.20558946354, 
    24.152084683517, 26.5222204649692, 23.3190351512451)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

            Constraint Observation for Crime = 0 Observation for Crime = 1 Total Observations  variable    value
1        No Constraint                      3124                       762               3886 Crime = 0 80.39115
2     Minor Constraint                      2484                       629               3113 Crime = 0 79.79441
3  Moderate Constraint                      3511                      1118               4629 Crime = 0 75.84792
4     Major Constraint                      4646                      1677               6323 Crime = 0 73.47778
5                Total                     13765                      4186              17951 Crime = 0 76.68096
6        No Constraint                      3124                       762               3886 Crime = 1 19.60885
7     Minor Constraint                      2484                       629               3113 Crime = 1 20.20559
8  Moderate Constraint                      3511                      1118               4629 Crime = 1 24.15208
9     Major Constraint                      4646                      1677               6323 Crime = 1 26.52222
10               Total                     13765                      4186              17951 Crime = 1 23.31904
```

I am trying to create something like this:

```
graph %>% 
    mutate(`Constraint` = fct_relevel(`Constraint`, "No Constraint", "Minor Constraint", "Moderate Constraint", "Major Constraint")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = `Constraint`, y = value, fill = variable, label=sprintf("%.02f %%", round(value, digits = 1)))) + 
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
              vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
              size = 4) +           
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.5) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
    geom_signif(stat="identity",
              data=data.frame(x=c(0.875, 1.875), xend=c(1.125, 2.125),
                              y=c(5.8, 8.5), annotation=c("**", "NS")),
              aes(x=x,xend=xend, y=y, yend=y, annotation=annotation)) +
    geom_signif(comparisons=list(c("treatment", "control")), annotations="***",
              y_position = 9.3, tip_length = 0, vjust=0.4)
```

Hoping for an appearance close to the following picture:

[image]

But it gives the error that the value is not found, while the value is in the data. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: From which package does `geom_signif` come from?

Comment: and what are two `geom_signif` doing in one call?

Comment: @MonJeanJean My apologies, `geom_signif` is from `library(gg_signif)`. I will add this. (Someone already did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `fill` and `label` in `geom_col` and `geom_text` -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)

graph %>% 
  mutate(`Constraint` = fct_relevel(`Constraint`, "No Constraint", "Minor Constraint", "Moderate Constraint", "Major Constraint")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Constraint`, y = value)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge', aes(fill = variable)) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            aes(label=sprintf("%.02f %%", round(value, digits = 1))),
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 4) +           
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.5) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
  geom_signif(stat="identity",
              data=data.frame(x=c(0.875, 1.875), xend=c(1.125, 2.125),
                              y=c(5.8, 8.5), annotation=c("**", "NS")),
              aes(x=x,xend=xend, y=y, yend=y, annotation=annotation))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak. Do you have any idea why the positions of the percentages resulting from `geom_text` are in the middle of the pair of bars instead of the middle of the bars? I can also ask a separate question for this if you like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405358/geom-text-positioning-applies-to-both-bars-together-instead-separately